# Filter XSS in href attribute?

Tags: javascript, xss

In my blog, I let users submit links like this `<a href="$">link text</a>` whatever they input will stay inside the "href" attribute only, even if they try to close " or > I use html_entity_decode() function, then filterd the keyword `javascript:`

My questions are:

1. Is it enough to prevent javascript being excuted?
2. Is it better to filter the keyword `javascript`?
3. Can data uri `data:` pose the same threat as `javascript:` ?
4. If I filter any input that doesn't start with http, https, ftp... and **#** (I need this). Is it enough?

My main question is 4th. I'm ok with yes/no answers for first 3 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's **not** sufficient in long term. Have a look at [HTML5 Security Cheatsheet](http://heideri.ch/jso/) and you'll see that most of the current XSS vectors are very sophisticated, with `javascript` and `data` being frequent targets.

So you cannot just rely on *blocking* known bad values ("if it doesn't start with..."). You should only *allow* known good values instead ("does it only start with...").

Which is not that difficult because you're dealing with URLs whose syntax is defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which, apart from somewhat weird naming scheme, is quite helpful with most of the patterns defined in section 3.2. You can use one of the standard URL parsing classes (I can recommend some for Python) and then validate each of the tokens according to your needs.

Remember that `#` is called "fragment" in the RFC.